# Запуск демона из PHP или любого другого ЯП

Tags: php, python

Есть программа написанная на python, я написал к ней панель управления (веб-морду), допустим при нажатии на кнопочку шел GET запрос к php скирпту, который запускает программу на питоне. Но беда в том, что проходит определенный отрезок времени и все накрывается медным тазом. Я пользуюсь функцией system() в PHP, она ждет завершения выполнения скрипта, однако если остановить выполнение скрипта процесс будет еще несколько минут жить. Ну собственно сам вопрос, как запустить python скрипт с PHP, но что бы PHP не ждал выполнения процесса, а просто запустил его в качестве демона, либо можно сделать прокладку на другом ЯП, что бы с него реализовать эту задачу

Comment: Наверное, вам нужен CGI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогично этому: http://www.cyberforum.ru/nodejs/thread1331141.html

Используй команду `nohup`. При необходимости перенаправь потоки вывода.