# Остановка команды в exec при завершении скрипта

Tags: php, linux, php7

на сервере запускаю php скрипт, который с помощью функции exec() запускает сторонний софт, запускается все отлично, но если php скрипт завершит работу, или умрет, то даже если работа стороннего софта, который запускался через exec(), еще не завершена, он тоже умирает. Как правильно запускать стороннее программы, что бы они работали вне зависимости от работы скрипта. Пробовал запускать с & в конце, не помогает.

Код в `systemd`

```
[Unit]
Description=PHP Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root

Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0

WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/html/realtime.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null

Restart=always
RestartSec=40

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что у вас там на самом деле. Насколько я помню, `exec()` должен дождаться выполнения внешней программы, чтобы продолжить работу php скрипта далее. По вашему описанию это все выглядит как параллельная работа скрипта и внешней программы. Так ли все на самом деле, как вы описываете? Внешняя программа случаем не демон со своим скриптом запуска?

Comment: Внешняя программа не демон, просто софт, `exec() ` или ждет выполнения, или, если добавить в конец команды `&`, продолжает работу. Сам php скрипт я запускаю через systemd, что бы перезапускать, если упадет, и уже с этого php скрипта запускаю, через `exec() `, внешнюю программу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449225/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , спасибо за наводку, но не помогло. Но, сейчас начал пробовать и попробовал еще по другому, я выше писал, что использую `systemd`, что бы скрипт, который запускает внешнюю программу, поднимался, если вдруг упадет, так вот, если этот скрипт запускается из-под `systemd` и завершает работу, то внешняя программа тоже останавливается, если же скрипт запустить просто в консоли, в случае если он остановится или завершит свою работу, то внешняя программа продолжит свою работу. Код в `systemd` приложил к первому посту, если это существенно

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в РНР, но по правилам запуска демонов, необходимо ОТСОЕДИНИТЬСЯ от сессии, в которой был запущен процесс. Иначе, при закрытии сессии, созданный процесс тоже будет убит. В С для этого используется вызов *setsid()*.

Answer (score 0):

В раздел [Service] добавьте `RemainAfterExit=yes` Кмк дожно помоч.

## Ибо сказано в `man 5 systemd.service`:

> RemainAfterExit=
>   Takes a boolean value that specifies whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited. Defaults to no.

Ну или зациклить Ваш скрипт внутри. Не знаю как это сделать в PHP. Но в bash это делается приблизительно так:

```
while :; do
    # тут собственно те действия что должен выполнять скрипт
    sleep 1
done.
```

И еще. Выражение `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null` можно записать короче.
К примеру:
`> /dev/null 2>&1` или `&>/dev/null`

Comment: "_зациклить Ваш скрипт внутри. Не знаю как это сделать в PHP_" - почти так же и в php: `while (true) { //code }`